# Java - use of super() in the given example

Tags: java, super

I've just started to learn the Spring framework and I found some tutorial at javatpoint.com.

I've got this code (nothing special, only prints some questions and answers):

```
private int id;
private String name;
private Map<Answer,User> answers;

public Question(){}
public Question(int id, String name, Map<Answer,User> answers){
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.answers = answers;
}
```

My question is : Why is he using that **empty constructor** and the keyword **super()** ? The app works without them and I don't get what are they good for in this code.

P.S. : There is no super class or something like that.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly call `super()`. The compiler inserts it if omitted (provided the super class has a no-arg ctor; otherwise you do have to call it explicitly).

Comment: @AndyTurner So no need to use `super()`. But what about the empty constructor `Question()`?

Comment: It will make sure that object can be created without passing parameters

Comment: Right, that is a perfect example: a call to `super()` is inserted there by the compiler. This is just self-inconsistent code.

Comment: not sure if this is relevant here, however, some frameworks/tools require a no-arg ctor to be able to instantiate objects (for example, Jackson json parser)

Comment: And yes, there is a super class: `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @Patrick That is not true, you can have constructor injection.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I don't think I understand your comment. a no-arg ctor is indeed required by Jackson (and some other frameworks) to instantiate objects. and once you have a non default ctor you need to explicitly define one to be able to call it.

Comment: and the question was about the no arg ctor of `Question` class, not its super.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A no-arg constructor (e.g., `Question()`) can be useful in several cases - if you're using a class as a bean and wish to lazily initialize its members, serializing it over GWT, etc.. Without any context provided in the example, this is indeed redundant.

The call to `super()` is completely redundant, and would be performed implicitly if no [other] call to `super` is specified.

Answer (score 1):

Empty constructor is not needed in most cases, only when you use your class in some poor framework like Hibernate or JPA, where you need empty constructor for the framework to create your class.
Then the empty constructor is for the framework and non-empty one is usually for tests or other usages.

In the example above I don't see any evidence that you use such framework so this empty constructor is not needed.

As for the `super()` it is NOT needed at all.